# Running total in per year ordered by person based on latest date info

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We try to calculate the running total in for each year ordered by person based on his latest date info. So i got an example for you how the data is ordered:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

So for each downloaded date we want to running total in of all persons ordered by year (now the year is only 2018)

What do we have so far:

```
sum(Amount)
over(partition by [Year],[Person]
order by [Enddate)
where max(Downloaded)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That is not a running total.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *window function*

```
select *,
        sum(Amount) over (partition by Year, Downloaded) RuningTotal 
from table t
```

Comment: probably don't need year

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery with a moving downloaded date range.

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    RunningTotalByDate = (
        SELECT
            SUM(N.Amount)
        FROM
            YourTable AS N
        WHERE
            N.Downloaded <= T.Downloaded)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
ORDER BY
    T.Downloaded ASC,
    T.Person ASC
```

Or with windowed `SUM()`. Do no include a `PARTITION BY` because it will reset the sum when the partitioned by column value changes.

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    RunningTotalByDate = SUM(T.Amount) OVER (ORDER BY T.Downloaded ASC)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
ORDER BY
    T.Downloaded ASC,
    T.Person ASC
```